# Suppressing the console window while running QT4 programs

Tags: c++, qt, codeblocks

I am trying to make an application using QT for C++ using codeblocks. Every time I run the application a command prompt window pops out followed by the gui for my application.

How do I suppress the command prompt window?

Answer (score 0):

Here the possible [answer](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/20168)

Just remove

> CONFIG += CONSOLE

from your .pro file

Yet another option for Code::Blocks. In IDE menu

> Project->Properties->Build Targets: change Type from "Console Application" to "GUI Application".

Found [here](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=8251.0;prev_next=prev) and [here](http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/main_codeblocks_en.html)

Comment: please sir,everybody is saying about .pro file ,actually where is its location??

Comment: Have you tried to search for *.pro within your project files? Or provide more details about your environment.

Comment: Sir, I am using codeblocks in Windows 7. I tried searching the project directory but couldn't find any pro files...